# Jquery .each get value

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(category, function (index, value) {
var addnew = '<div class="about">';
    addnew += '<div class="profile-title">';
    addnew += '<span>';
    addnew += '</span>';
    addnew += '</div>';
    addnew += '</div>';
});
```

I just want to get the value and put it in the SPAN TAG 
How to do that ?

Comment: why you put you jQuery inside a tilt sign?

Comment: sorry typo only

Comment: Whats your Problem @DaveManuel?

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, did not get you.

Comment: hello I just want to get the values in the category it is an array loop it and put in the span tag

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

you should use my code as below if you have the **category array** in `category` variable::

```
$.each(category, function (index, value) {
    var addnew = '<div class="about">';
    addnew += '<div class="profile-title">';
    addnew += '<span>' + value + '</span>';
    addnew += '</div>';
    addnew += '</div>';
});
```

Comment: @DaveManuel Yes, please check.

Comment: I have probkwn un my array now